# sketching sampling distribution

Tags: self-study, proportion, capture-mark-recapture

I have another question about distributions as I am going through an exercise. I apologize for posting on the other site by mistake.

Millions of birds are released, 100 of them have tags and 7 of the tagged birds are found to have returned to the release site. How do you sketch the sampling distribution of $\hat P$? If another 103 birds are tagged and nothing in their habitat has changed, what is the chance that more than 9% of these tagged birds will return to their release site?

Comment: Simply posting obvious questions is not going to get you any useful replies. You are expected to demonstrate some at least moderate effort at understanding the issues and concepts and at what point you are getting stuck.

Comment: (1) What is "P hat"? (2) The chance in the second question calls for a Binomial *prediction limit*.  This question is more complicated than it might look at first sight because the *true* proportion of returning birds is unknown and the 7/100 data give only a very rough sense of what that proportion really is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Poisson` or `Binomial` distribution. For example, based on your `p_hat=7/100=0.07`, the probability of more than `9%` of `103` birds that will return is estimated as:

```
 >1-pbinom(9, 103, 0.07)
[1] 0.1843168
```

Comment: Thanks Dadong, my excersise asks for a sketch of the distribution. By sketch do they mean graphing results or just estimating the p_hat and the other probability? I apologize, my knowledge of statistics is very limited and I am just trying to learn the concepts through some books and online tutorials.

Comment: "sketch" means "draw a picture" (usually by hand)

Comment: @dadong please make it clear that you are writing R code in your answer